# show div on click , then remove all on click

Tags: jquery

Trying to open each container div on click , then have button to remove all content. but when i reclick to show a div after removing , nothing will display http://jsfiddle.net/ZM9dL/467/

script

```
$('.menu>li.toggle6').on('click',function(e){
        $('.container').hide();
});
$('.menu>li').on('click',function(e){
    $('.container>.'+ e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

html

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="toggle1">One</li>
    <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
    <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
    <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
    <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
    <li class="toggle6">Remove All</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
    <div class="toggle1">Here are the contents of 1..</div>
    <div class="toggle2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
    <div class="toggle3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
    <div class="toggle4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
    <div class="toggle5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are hiding the container, so when you are clicking an item to show even though that items display is set the container is hidden so nothing is displayed.

One solution is to hide the toggle elements instead of container like

```js
$('.menu > li.toggle6').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.container > *').hide();
});
$('.menu > li').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.container > .' + e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="toggle1">One</li>
  <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
  <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
  <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
  <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
  <li class="toggle6">Remove All</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle1">Here are the contents of 1..</div>
  <div class="toggle2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
  <div class="toggle3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
  <div class="toggle4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
  <div class="toggle5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
```

Another option is to call show of the container in each click

```js
$('.menu > li.toggle6').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.container > *').hide();
});
$('.menu > li:not(.toggle6)').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.container').show().children('.' + e.target.classList[0]).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
.menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid tomato;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="toggle1">One</li>
  <li class="toggle2">Two</li>
  <li class="toggle3">Three</li>
  <li class="toggle4">Four</li>
  <li class="toggle5">Five</li>
  <li class="toggle6">Remove All</li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle1">Here are the contents of 1..</div>
  <div class="toggle2">Here are the contents of 2..</div>
  <div class="toggle3">Here are the contents of 3...</div>
  <div class="toggle4">Here are the contents of 4....</div>
  <div class="toggle5">Here are the contents of 5.....</div>
</div>
```